# How to work with hasClass in JQuery and add a class to the found values?

Tags: jquery

In JQuery, after doing the search with `hasClass()`, how do I add a class to the elements found? With $(this)?

In the example below that I tried to reproduce to explain my question, I searched with `hasClass()` for elements that have the `filter1_1` or `filter2_2` class and added a class to paint them in another color, that is, only the *News 3 3* should not be painted, what is the correct way to work?

```js
function filter(){
  if($('.news').hasClass('filter1_1') || $('.news').hasClass('filter2_2')){
    $(this).addClass('paint_news');
  }
}
filter();
```

```css
.paint_news{
  color: #d71f0b;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news filter1_1 filter2_2">
  News 1 2
</div>
<div class="news filter1_1 filter2_1">
  News 1 1
</div>
<div class="news filter1_3 filter2_3">
  News 3 3
</div>
```

Comment: Not need to iterate use `,` selector separator: `$(".news.filter1_1,.news.filter2_2").addClass("paint_news")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work... your `this` is not pointing to the element you desire.

It will be easier to let jQuery do the selecting like this:

```
function filter() {
  $('.news.filter1_1').addClass('paint_news');
  $('.news.filter2_2').addClass('paint_news');
}
```

If you want to iterate over the news element, use `each` like this:

```
function filter() {
  $('.news').each(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('filter1_1') || $(this).hasClass('filter2_2')){
      $(this).addClass('paint_news');
    }
  }
}
```

By the way, you can also regex the `hasClass` for multiple classes like this:

```
if($(this).attr('class').match(/filter1_1|filter2_2/)){
```